# capture selected text from inputTextArea primefaces jsf

Tags: ajax, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I want to capture selected text from `inputTextArea` on ajax `dblclick` or `select` event.How can I do this ? 
The code below selects everything in the text area (which I don't want). Thank you very much.

```
<h:form id="form">          
        <p:panel header="Select Text">  
            <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">  
                <h:outputText value="Text: " />  
                <p:inputTextarea id="textarea" 
                            value="#{selectedTextBean.selectedText}">  
                    <p:ajax event="select" update="selectedText" />  
                </p:inputTextarea>  
                <h:outputText id="selectedText" 
                          value="#{selectedTextBean.selectedText}" />
            </h:panelGrid>  
        </p:panel>               
</h:form>
```

Here is `SelectedTextBean`

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SelectedTextBean {

   public SelectedTextBean() {
   }
   private String selectedText;  

   public String getSelectedText() {
    return selectedText;
   }
   public void setSelectedText(String selectedText) {
    this.selectedText = selectedText;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that sending a parameter to a remote command as follows:

**The View**

```
<h:form id="form">          
    <p:panel header="Select Text">  
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">  
            <h:outputText value="Text: " />  
            <h:panelGroup>
                <p:inputTextarea id="textarea" 
                                 value="#{selectedTextBean.selectedText}" onselect="processSelection();" />
                <p:remoteCommand name="sendSelection" actionListener="#{selectedTextBean.onSelect}" update="selectedText" process="@this" />
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:outputText id="selectedText" 
                          value="#{selectedTextBean.selectedText}" />
        </h:panelGrid>  
    </p:panel>               
</h:form>
<script>
    function processSelection() {
        var selectedText = (!!document.getSelection) ? document.getSelection() :
                (!!window.getSelection) ? window.getSelection() :
                document.selection.createRange().text;
        sendSelection([{name: 'selectedText', value: selectedText}]);
    }
</script>
```

Note that the [text selection](http://snipplr.com/view/775/getselection/) changes depending on the browser.

**The Bean**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SelectedTextBean implements Serializable {

    public SelectedTextBean() {
    }
    private String selectedText;

    public void onSelect() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Map map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        selectedText = (String) map.get("selectedText");
    }

    public String getSelectedText() {
        return selectedText;
    }

    public void setSelectedText(String selectedText) {
        this.selectedText = selectedText;
    }
}
```

Comment: problem solved.Thank you, I tried to update the captured text in the text area itself but couldnt, is there any way of uniquely identifying the text captured so that it can be updated later. for eg. 'one two one' , would be something like 'one two three'

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin [jquery-textrange](https://github.com/dwieeb/jquery-textrange).

***xhtml***

```
<p:inputTextarea onselect="setSelectedText()" />                     
<p:remoteCommand name="setSelectedTextCommand" 
                 actionListener="#{mainBean.setSelectedText()}"
                 update="currentSelectedText" />
Selected Text is: 
            <h:outputText value="#{mainBean.selectedTextInArea}" 
                          id="currentSelectedText" />

<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-textrange.js" />
<script>
   function setSelectedText() {
      var range = $('.ui-inputtextarea').textrange();// general selector
      setSelectedTextCommand([{name: 'selectedText', value: range.text}]); 
   }
</script>
```

***Bean***

```
private String selectedTextInArea;

public void setSelectedText() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    selectedTextInArea = (String) map.get("selectedText");
}

public String getSelectedTextInArea() {
    return selectedTextInArea;
}

public void setSelectedTextInArea(String selectedTextInArea) {
    this.selectedTextInArea = selectedTextInArea;
}
```

And Here's a live [demo](http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/DailyLab/textArea/main.xhtml) on Primefaces TextArea Selection, and on [github](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/webapp/textArea/main.xhtml).

Comment: I think event is not firing, I added `styleClass=ui-inputtextarea` to the `inputTextArea` but still not working for me , what am I missing ?

Comment: The css class is already shipped with the component of primefaces.. no need to add it. anyway you can select with the ID of the textArea .. which is `form:textarea`